# Translation lengths in CAT(0) spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory, alexandrov-geometry

> Let $a,b$ be two loxodromic isometries of a CAT(0) space. Assume that, for every $n \geq 1$, $a^nb$ is also loxodromic. Is it possible for the translation length of $a^nb$ to be bounded independently of $n$?

First, I thought as obvious that the translation length of $a^nb$ has to tend to $+ \infty$ as $n \to + \infty$, but I may have been misled by the CAT(-1) case (where this is clearly true). Now, I go back and forth between a possible counterexample and an easy argument I am missing...

Comment: Could you remind us of the definition of loxodromic?

Comment: Loxodromic = there exists a bi-infinite geodesic on which the isometry acts as a translation.

Comment: @PeterKosenko: You should write $\ell(a^nb)= \lim\limits_{k \to + \infty} d(x_0,(a^nb)^kx_0)/k$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct -- and now I realize that it doesn't immediately imply your statement...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the following two transformations of $\mathbb{R}^3$: $a:(x,y,z)\mapsto (x+1,y,z)$ and $b:(x,y,z)\mapsto (-x,-y,z+1)$.  The translation axis for $a^nb$ is  the line $x=n/2$, $y=0$ and $a^nb$ translates this line by a distance of 1, independent of $n$.

Comment: I've just realized that the $y$-coordinate isn't needed: $a$ and $b$ both preserve the plane $y=0$, so there is a simpler example in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: This even works restricted to the $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is the xz-plane.

Comment: (Sorry, simultaneous comment!)

Comment: You were quicker than me Matt - should I delete my comment?

Comment: I don't know the rules! I'm inclined to just leave everything.